# Question about unbiased estimators

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, estimation

We define the unbiased estimator as 
Let $X_1,X_2,....,X_n$ be a random sample from a population with the pdf $P_{\theta}$,An estimator $T(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ is said to be unbiased for estimating the parameter $\theta$ if $$E(T(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=\theta$$

What I don't understand is the following example:

if $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ is a random sample from a normal population $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then show that $T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mu^2+1$.
$\textbf{Solution:}$ we have to show that $E(T)=\mu^2+1$
That is $E(\frac{x_{1}^{2}+.....+x_{n}^{2}}{n})=\mu^2+1$.

In the book, I am referring they solve this question by saying that $E(x_1)=\mu$ that is each $x_i$ will follow a normal distribution,My question is how $x_i$ follows a normal distribution?? I mean $x_i$ are not random variables they are just observed values.And why are we taking those values same as the population mean?Please someone explain what mistake I am making here?
{One thing we know that $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are the observations of the random variable $X$ for the population,so if we go on a field and collect the data we get $X_1=x_1,....,X_n=x_n$ where $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are sample data.}

Comment: Random sample means the $x_j$ are i.i.d.

Comment: Okay so that means they all have same expectations .One more question is how $E(x_i)=\mu$,I mean $\mu$ was the expectation value of the population and here we have taken a sample.

Comment: You should treat $x_j$ as random because you have not actually observed its value yet. If we think of it as fixed, then what does the expectation of an estimator even mean? Once you actually have a sample in hand, then $T(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is fixed. But until then, it is a random variable, and here we are interested in its distribution. Perhaps here the notation is a bit misleading. We typically use $X$ to denote the random variable and $x$ for its observed value.

Comment: Thanks, this I understood, But one more thing is why $E(x_j)=\mu$ ,I mean $\mu$ is the expectation of population right and $E(x_j)$ is the expectation of samples, So why we are taking is also same as expectation of population?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The population is $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. A random sample means $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d. copies all distributed according to $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: Let me try to clarify my doubt, Let $X$ be a random variable associated with the population, so as given in the question $ N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ here we have $E(X)=\mu$, Now let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ is a random sample, as you said that it i.i.d so they all have the same distribution and all the parameters will be same. So my question was why we are taking $E(X_i)=\mu$, the doubt here I have is that from a population we have selected a sample $X_1,...,X_n$ right then why $E(X_i)=\mu?$ I mean we are choosing a subset of population as a sample so it should have different expectation value.

Answer (score 1):

The term "population" should not be taken too literally here. This is a question in Probability theory, which is then used in Statistics. The random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$  (using capital letters is a bit better here)  form an i.i.d. sample from a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$  **distribution**. The word "population" and the lower case $x_i$ are used just so that people will feel this is a question in statistics. But at this stage there is no population, just a  distribution. In advanced statistics there are procedures, such as the bootstrap and the jackknife, where one actually resamples from a population.

One small correction: The average $T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mu^2+\sigma^2$, rather than $\mu^2+1$.